# How to integrate existing classes to a new Swing project

Tags: java, swing

I have some Java classes that I have tested using Windows console. Now I need to develop an interface which can be graphical or text based and I would like to try Java Swing. I am new to Java and Swing.

So, my question is, how do I integrate the classes I already have into a Swing project in order to, for example, instantiate them when a button is clicked and call its methods?

Comment: You can copy paste the Java files into the new project...

Comment: If you're starting new, I would recommend using JavaFX instead of Swing, as it is the newer technology.

Comment: I kindly ask you to be more specific. What files should I copy (.java, .class)? To which folder should I copy them? I copied my ".java" class files to the folder where Swing ".form and .java" files are located and ran the project but I get an exception: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: csce315Test.dbEngine

Comment: I have not been able to solve my issue. Can someone please provide any feedback?